# Difficulties installing Nebular on to my existing angular project

Tags: angular, nebular

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrAci.png)

I am trying to add Nebular on to my existing angular project and keep getting errors, i am following this tutorial.

https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/guides/add-into-existing-project#install-nebular

Comment: please add a detailed description of your errors in the description and don't add the image as a link

Answer (score 2):

You can't add nebular via schematics for angular prior to 7. There is no [@schematics/angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@schematics/angular) stable package for 6. Please, update angular to 7 version and then try again.

If you can't up angular version, you can install nebular@2.0.2 manually, it works with angular 6. See [docs](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/guides/add-into-existing-project#manually) for guidance with the manual install.